# epspdfconversion problems in xelatex

Tags: xetex, epstopdf

I am using xelatex and I am trying to use `epspdfconversion` package to on-the-fly remove unnecessary empty margins from my figures. The figures themselves are dynamically generated and calculating a tight bounding box via `bbox` option of `epspdf` seemed like a good idea.

Unfortunately, epspdfconversion does not seem to play nice with xelatex. Below is a minimum working example:

```
\documentclass{tufte-handout}

%\usepackage{xltxtra}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[bbox,pdftopdf=true,suffix=]{epspdfconversion}

\begin{document}
\includegraphics{unnamed-chunk-2.pdf}
\end{document}`
```

However, if uncomment `\usepackage{xltxtra}` and compile it xelatex I get the following message:

```
Package epstopdf Warning: Drivers other than `pdftex.def' are not supported.

epspdfconversion.sty is using epstopdf.sty with the following setup:
    update=true,
    verbose=true,
    prefersuffix=true,
    suffix=,
    option outdir not set. Default: same directory as the .eps-source-file
    append,
    enable
epspdf is used with the following command:
    epspdf --bbox <file> 
Package epspdfconversion Info: 
(epspdfconversion)             epspdf --bbox <file> is used to convert eps-pdf
(epspdfconversion)             (not epstopdf (script))
(epspdfconversion)              on input line 334.
! Undefined control sequence.
l.345 \epstopdfDeclareGraphicsRule
                                  {.eps}{pdf}{.pdf}{%
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

This seems to be a  conflict between xelatex and `epspdfconversion.sty` I am using extra OTF fonts and using xelatex seems necessary. Does anyone have any recommendations for solving or bypassing this problem?

Comment: `epstopdf` works only with the `pdftex` driver for `graphics` , as the first warning tells you. However, `lualatex` can be used as well as `pdflatex`.

Comment: @egreg Please make that an answer here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`epstopdf` works only with the `pdftex` driver for `graphics`, as the first warning tells you. However, `lualatex` can be used as well as `pdflatex`.